# Having three columns layout in PDF using itext7

Tags: java, itext

I am new to itext7.
I saw an example about columndocumentrenderer. code below.

```
package com.itextpdf.highlevel.chapter02;

import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.ColumnDocumentRenderer;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AreaBreak;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.hyphenation.HyphenationConfig;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.AreaBreakType;
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.test.annotations.WrapToTest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author RNDPC-03
 */@WrapToTest
 public class C02E08_JekyllHydeV4 {


     public static final String SRC = "src/main/resources/txt/jekyll_hyde.txt";
     public static final String DEST = "results/chapter02/jekyll_hyde_v4.pdf";

     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
         File file = new File(DEST);
         file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
         new C02E08_JekyllHydeV4().createPdf(DEST);
     }

     public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
         //Initialize PDF document
         PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));

         // Initialize document
         Document document = new Document(pdf);

         //Set column parameters
         float offSet = 36;
         float gutter = 23;
         float columnWidth = (PageSize.A4.getWidth() - offSet * 2) / 2 - gutter;
         float columnHeight = PageSize.A4.getHeight() - offSet * 2;

         //Define column areas
         Rectangle[] columns = {
             new Rectangle(offSet, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
             new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth + gutter, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight)};
         document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));    

         PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
         PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);
         document.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED)
             .setFont(font)
             .setHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("en", "uk", 3, 3));

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(SRC));
         String line;
         Paragraph p;
         boolean title = true;
         AreaBreak nextArea = new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_AREA);
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             p = new Paragraph(line);
             if (title) {
                 p.setFont(bold).setFontSize(12);
                 title = false;
             }
             else {
                 p.setFirstLineIndent(36);
             }
             if (line.isEmpty()) {
                 document.add(nextArea);
                 title = true;
             }
             document.add(p);
         }

         //Close document
         document.close();
     }
}
```

now this will have a result of this . picture below

[image]

now I want to make it into a three(3) column. how to do this? please anyone? or just guide me. thank you!

Comment: Dear downvoters, would you mind telling why you downvote. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why they down-voted, then again, I don't know why my answer wasn't accepted either...

Answer (score 2):

Here is where you define two columns:

```
float offSet = 36;
float gutter = 23;
float columnWidth = (PageSize.A4.getWidth() - offSet * 2) / 2 - gutter;
float columnHeight = PageSize.A4.getHeight() - offSet * 2;

//Define column areas
Rectangle[] columns = {
    new Rectangle(offSet, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
    new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth + gutter, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight)};
```

Changing this to three columns is a no-brainer.

Just replace all of the above by something like this:

```
Rectangle[] columns = {
    new Rectangle(20, 20, 180, 802),
    new Rectangle(207, 15, 180, 802),
    new Rectangle(394, 15, 180, 802) };
```

Now that `columns` has three `Rectangle` elements, three columns will be drawn. Feel free to adapt the values of `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` in the `Rectangle` constructor if the three columns don't have the desired size.

Comment: Hello Sir Bruno, thank you it works well, now my problem is that is this code limited to txt file only? ive tried using pdf and the output is not good. do you know how? my documents are in pdf not in text format

Comment: If your original document format is PDF, it should be obvious to you that the code given in this answer doesn't work. Your comment is a completely new question that is totally unrelated to your original question, hence you should **post it as a new question.** Be aware that PDF is **not a word processing format.** A page is a page is a page. You can't expect the content of a PDF to behave as text. All content on a page is added at absolute positions, not necessarily in the order you'd expect.